# Regex to match two expressions in any location

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

My input string is like this:

```
<div class="a-column a-span4 a-text-left a-nowrap">
   <span class="a-text-bold">Tom Dick Harry</span>
   <span class="a-text-bold">Tom Harry Dick Can Have Dick Harry</span>
  <span class="a-text-bold">Tom Harry</span>
</div>
<div id="buyNewInner" class="rbbContent dp-accordion-inner">
    Sold by <a href='/gp/help/seller/at-a-glance.html/ref=dp_merchant_link?ie=UTF8&amp;isAmazonFulfilled=1&amp;seller=A36YG4CRXUNHP3'>CAC Media</a> and <a href='/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&amp;ref=dp_fulfillment&amp;nodeId=106096011' id='SSOFpopoverLink'>Should Also Match This(99)</a>.
    Sold by <a href='/gp/help/seller/at-a-glance.html/ref=dp_merchant_link?ie=UTF8&amp;isAmazonFulfilled=1&amp;seller=A36YG4CRXUNHP3'>CAC Media</a> and <a href='/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&amp;ref=dp_fulfillment&amp;nodeId=106096011' id='SSOFpopoverLink'>Should Also Match This</a>.
```

I am trying to use regex to match the presence of both the these conditions:
Presence of all three words `Tom` `Dick` `Harry` in exact same sequence and `Should Also Match This` followed by any 2 digit number.

So ideally the regex would match `Tom Dick Harry` and `Should Also Match This(99)`
I am using .Net.

Comment: Match them according to what rules? Do you mean you want to check for those specific phrases? You don't need regex for that. Use [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/wH0oM0/1 ?

Comment: Yeah, I fear I'm with Ant P on this one. I think a regex is overkill, from what it looks like you're trying to do. Even if you're concerned about the ordering, which it doesn't appear you are, I would just use `IndexOf`. Regexes are great, but they can be hard to debug, and for something as simple as this, it just doesn't seem worth the hassle.

Comment: I am not sure why the negative vote on this one. The example surely doesnt call for a regex and I should have been more explicit. `String.Contains` can solve it too. But the reason for using regex is in my actual implementation I need to use a bit more complex regex rather than the just matching phrases mentioned above. So, my question should ideally have been how do I match two regex. Hope that clarifies. And if the down voter can pls revert it, if he thinks its now an apt reason.

Comment: Maybe you should ammend your original question then, to better reflect what it is you're trying to achieve and why it is you need a regular expression for it. Personally, I'm all for regular expressions, for performance reasons but, in the case of your original question, I'd be hard pressed to see a need for one.

Comment: Done, edited the question to substantiate use of regex

Comment: @AvinashRaj have checked your answer. Is there a way that `Regex.IsMatch` will return false with your expression even though only one of the phrases matches? Right now, if the string has the two phrases, it matches and return true, but if I remove one of the phrases from the input string, `Regex.IsMatch` returns true too.

Answer (score 0):

`.*(?=.*My name is Sine Nomen).*(?=.*And This Is a Test\(\d\d\)).*`

Will match for

`My name is Sine Nomen And This Is a Test(99)`

and also for the reverse

`And This Is a Test(99) My name is Sine Nomen`

Comment: Thx for checking @Sine Nomen. However, when testing this doesnt seem to work with the test string. https://regex101.com/r/qZ1iS6/1

Comment: I am not entirely sure why; something about the markup language is throwing the regular expression off. Just try it with just your 2 required strings, you'll see it does indeed match.

Comment: Checked with a simple input string. Still doesnt seem to work. https://regex101.com/r/qZ1iS6/4

Comment: Right, it's the separate lines. You'll have to look into incorporating a check for newlines in the regular expression, that should fix it. https://www.google.nl/search?q=regular+expressions+newlines&oq=regular+expressions+newlines&aqs=chrome..69i57.4740j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8